# Clone Android Studio project from Gitlab local server

Tags: gitlab, android-studio-3.0

I have a Gitlab repository path like http://192.168.1.10/xyz/myproject. I'm going to clone the project into android studio but it does not ask for username and password and shows authentication error.  First time it asked for username and password. How I can solve this?

Comment: Try the url provided by gitlab (usually has `.git`) but add your username before hostname, like (`http://<username>@192.168.1.10/xyz/myproject.git`) - you have copy button for the https/ssh git url

Comment: have not .git in URL?  please see : https://www.londonappdeveloper.com/how-to-clone-a-github-project-on-android-studio/

Comment: @azbarcea It does not solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `git config credential.helper`.

Depending on your OS, you might have invalid credentials already cached for http://192.168.1.10/, which would then result in failed `git` clone/push/pull commands.

See the credential deletion [for Mac](https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/) or [Windows](https://uwaterloo.ca/information-systems-technology/services/nexus/nexus-troubleshooting-guide/clearing-cachedsaved-windows-credentials).